# Workflow with designer using JavaScript Frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, workflow, reactjs

I am currently working in a project with a Designer/UX Guy. He can do pretty decent designs using CSS/HTML and some little JavaScript (with jQuery) for effects only.

Our first workflow was something like that *(we used backbone at the time)*:

- He created first iteration of design
- I implemented app logic etc
- He changed something on design
- I had to manually go through the edited files and find templates in code and edit stuff so it worked with app again
- Repeat above 2 steps N times and you will see the problem (we iterate a lot in early stage)

Then AngularJS came and things looked a lot better. He could create whole design and I would only prepare some directives or I would manually just tweak the HTML (easy&fast stuff - no need to move HTML to other files...). I explained how directives work so he could bind events, toggle classes - nothing fancy only basic stuff he could grasp easily.

This was a lot better approach and we sped up significantly with our development - I also had more motivation since I didn't have to do boring part of connecting everything together...

Now lots of people are criticising Angular and embracing React, and I was thinking of migrating to react. It looks good and all but me and the designer guy will be at the beginning again. What is your workflow with designers on a project? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Reactjs brings a lot of good features to your application, but you probably already know the big differences between angular and react.

So back to your question. One problem with react that are relevant to your question is that it is a new way of thinking. This means that it, for some people, are a little harder to learn than other frameworks. 
Your UX guy may struggle to get into the react-spirit due to that it also works as a templating-framework. This means that you have to write HTML through the JavaScript code. If you use JSX, the UX guy can at least recognise the HTML tags and do alterations. If you are not using JSX, the UX guy have to learn Reactjs, how to create elements, adding classes etc.

CSS is the same in both react and angular so that will not make a difference.

My personal experience from a project I am working on is that it is not a big problem to use react with UX developers/consultants. This is because it is often me or other developers that actually changes the HTML-elements. Alone or in coherence with a JavaScript alterations.

So my conclusion is: 
If you are on a hard deadline I would stay with angular since its less to learn and the UX guy can help you more directly. If your focus is performance and the deadline is not so hard (and both of you are eager to learn) I would definitely go for react.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big advantage using React when working with a designer - 
You can take his photoshop layers and make them your components and vice-versa. The structure of the HTML is logical so it's easy to grasp and change things locally. the best approach concerning CSS is to divide it to components (using Sass/Less or require/webpack to regroup them).

At the bottom line - there may be advantages of either framework, and developers have their own preferences, but concerning UX and design - it is more convenient and will speed up your work.